# How to customize testng report's email subject according to Success/Failure?

Tags: maven-2, testng, pom.xml

I am able to send testng report via pom.xml. Email goes to people on both Success and failure of build. Now as this reports goes everyday, I want Developers to see the email report only when it fails and so I want to change the subject of email that I sent. On Success subject should be "Test results : Build Success" and on failure "Test results : Build Failed"
My pom.xml looks like this (Email configuration part) - How can I do this??

```
<from>qa@qateam.com</from>
<subject>Test Results</subject>

<mailhost></mailhost>
<receiver>Alldev@devteam.com</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Jenkins to do this.  Add plugins for testng, mark the build as failed if mvn test has failures and use the email plugin to send customized emails.

Comment: there are so many ..which plugins you are talking about. As of now I am using maven's postman plugin to send mails. Where do I mention in pom that if build fails give this subject in mail and success give another subject...